# Severity: Warning Message: ftp_chmod() [function.ftp-chmod]: Permissions changed on

Tags: ftp, php

I am having an issue with php `ftp_chmod()`,  not really what is going on.

The directory permissions are being changed, but PHP is throwing a warning essentially just telling me they were changed.

I am hoping this is just an idiot moment for me. Below is the warning that is getting thrown and below that is the line of code.

Again, the permissions are being changed correctly, just having an issue with the warning being thrown:

> Severity: Warning
>   Message: ftp_chmod() [function.ftp-chmod]: Permissions changed on /public_html/pathToMyDir
>   Filename: models/inventory_model.php
>   Line Number: 63

Line 63 is below:

```
if (ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $currentFolder.$imgName) !== false) {
    echo "chmoded successfully to 0777\n";
} else {
    echo "could not chmod \n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could quiet the error with:

```
if (@ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $currentFolder.$imgName) !== false) {
```

Comment: But this does not fix the problem.

Comment: This will change the permissions, but it still isn't solving the issue.

Comment: So another interesting thing, it seems to be caching my last ftp command or something as well.  I sent a rename command using ftp_exec and it is returning a message containing the last ftp command that was executed.   For example I am getting this message on a line that is trying to rename a file.  Message: ftp_exec() [function.ftp-exec]: "/public_html/mySite/media/521" : The directory was successfully created      I am super confused now.