# php ftp returning last command

Tags: ftp, php

I figured I would make a new question for this since it isn't the same as my last question which I am also trying to work around. ([Severity: Warning Message: ftp_chmod() [function.ftp-chmod]: Permissions changed on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995494/severity-warning-message-ftp-chmod-function-ftp-chmod-permissions-changed))

I am trying to use PHP [`ftp_exec`](http://php.net/ftp_exec) to rename a file; however, it is outputting the result of the last ftp command that I ran.  Below is the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
> Message: ftp_exec() [function.ftp-exec]: Permissions changed on /public_html/admin/tempUpload/1356124170
>
> Filename: models/inventory_model.php
> Line Number: 80

Line 80 is below:

```
$command = 'rename '.$currentFolder.$imgName.' '.$newFolderFile.$imgName;
ftp_exec($conn_id, $command);
```

And several lines above that is where I am changing the permissions on the mentioned directory.  Also, the rename exec command isn't doing anything, but all the commands above it are working as expected.

```
ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $currentDir);
```

Do I need to reconnect for every command? Or is there some sort of clearing that I need to do prior to running the `ftp_exec` command?  Also, when I run the exact same `ftp_exec` while being connected to ftp via cmd it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Severity: Warning Message: ftp\_chmod() \[function.ftp-chmod\]: Permissions changed on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995494/severity-warning-message-ftp-chmod-function-ftp-chmod-permissions-changed) - Instead of creating a new question, please edit your existing one, as both belong together.

Comment: So you finally read the post then huh?  Since I included that link in the original post.

Comment: Also, it is not the same.  As the other one is concerning why it is returning tat warning when it is supposed to be returning s boolean value.  This one concerns as to why line 80 is outputting a warning which looks like the warning that should have been from another php line, speficically ftp_chmod.

Comment: Please only paste the original PHP error warnings. The format you post here has been modified and is not the original PHP warning. There might be another component changing the correct error information ins something different or similar, so better relate to the standard language feature so everybody knows what you're concerned about.

Comment: The warning I pasted is exactly what was Outputted on the screen.  Is there somewhere else I should look for the warning?  Should I post a screenshot of the warning? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Enable PHP error logging, paste the warning from the PHP error logs.